# Match date and id and time Aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

my schema like this

```
customer : {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Customer'
    },
    doctor: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'Doctor'
    },
    return_patient  : { 
        type: Boolean, 
        default: false 
    },
    consultation: {
        type: Number,    //1: Phone, 2: Video
        required: true
    }, 
    fee: {
        type: Number
    },
    payment: {
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed
    },
    schedule_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    schedule_time: {
        from: {
           type: String   
        },   
        to: {
           type: String    
        } 
    },
```

now i want check doctor availablity
from req.query

```
localhost:9000/api/appointment/doctor-available?doctor=5e83704aadca4064368ff24f&date=2020-04-01&from=5.30&to=6.00
```

match the table and query if data came means doctor is not available otherwise
doctor available

Comment: This type of questions are answered earlier under tag `mongodb` please post your trail attempts & raise a question on errors/issues.. Also try to store dates in `Date` format doing `gte` or `lte` on  two strings is not ideal.

Comment: time only string
date type should by Date only

Comment: These `from=5.30&to=6.00`, try to save as int/double or save those as dates, cause '5.30' is not ideal to compare, So can you give us sample docs & required o/p.